# How to extract only Min Max and Average of thread groups

Tags: jmeter, max, average, min

I have a scenario, where I have an api where 50, 100 and 500 users are hitting the api at the ramp up period of 1 second as in -

```
50 users - 1 rampup
   + Duration assertion - 100
100 users - rampup
   + Duration assertion - 200
500 users - 1 rampup
   + duration assertion - 300
```

Now I run the command in Jenkins

```
path/jMeter/bin/jmeter -n -R {remoteIP} -t test.jmx -l path/${BUILD_NUMBER}_result.jtl -e -o path/${BUILD_NUMBER}_report/
```

Now in Jmeter how to calculate min, max and average of 50, 100 and 500 users each and save in a file say resultminmaxavg.csv so that I can pick the file and publish through mail.

Like below -

```
Users     Min    Max   Avg
50        378    455
100       333    655
500       322    344
```

How to calculate the data in JMeter? Attaching image:

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is aby adding an SummaryReport listener which you need to configure as following:

- Define a rootPath in the testPlan variables;
- Define 3 variables: 50maxThreads, 100maxThreads, and 500maxThreads
- In each ThreadGroup, define each value of the 3 variables above as number of threads,

In each SummaryReport listener of the X users thread grup, the filename is to be configured as following:

```
${rootPath}/${50maxThreads}_test_outcome.csv
```

Good luck, I have not tried this, but it should work

Comment: Thanks Rami. i see under /jmeter/bin/rootpath/${50maxThreads}_test_outcome.csv got created but i do not see the summary report. It is default csv that got created with below headers
timeStamp elapsed label responseCode responseMessage threadName dataType success failureMessage bytes sentBytes grpThreads allThreads URL Latency SampleCount ErrorCount IdleTime Connect

Comment: There should be an Average avaialble for the XThreads threadGroup ( per sample ) but as I understand, you have only one sample / API call.
In the Summary Report listener, there is a configure button - check it out and select from there what exactly you need.

Comment: Rami i have attached the screenshot of the test. Still no luck.